# How is to implement K-Means clustering algorithm with Cosine Distance measure?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, cosine-similarity

I need to run K-means clustering algorithm to cluster textual data but by using cosine distance measure instead of Euclidean distance. Any reliable implementation of this in python?

***Edit:***

I have tried to use NLTK as following:

```
NUM_CLUSTERS=3
kclusterer = KMeansClusterer(NUM_CLUSTERS, distance= 
            nltk.cluster.util.cosine_distance, repeats=25)

clstr = kclusterer.cluster(X, clusters=False, trace=False)
print (clstr)
```

But it gives me error:

```
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

X here is a TF-IDF matrix of shape (15, 155).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it yourself: [https://stanford.edu/~cpiech/cs221/handouts/kmeans.html](https://stanford.edu/%7Ecpiech/cs221/handouts/kmeans.html)

just change the distance measruing entry. The distance measuring is in the for loop over `i` of the pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NLTK for this. The K-means from NLTK allows you to specify which measure of distance you want to use.

[nltk](https://www.nltk.org/)